# программа вылетает на этапе заполнения [N][N] матрицы

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

Вычислить сумму элементов матрицы [N][N], лежащих по диагонали и по двум сторонам как показано на ASCII рисунке (треугольник).

```
    |0|1|.|.|N|
    |1|-|-|-|-|
    |.|-|-|-|-|
    |.|-|-|-|-|
    |N|-|-|-|-|

    |0|-|-|-|x| N
    |-|-|-|x|x|
    |-|-|x|-|x|
    |-|x|-|-|x|
    |x|x|x|x|x|

    N
```

Написал не очень оптимальные циклы, т.к. при N = 1000, программа вылетает на этапе заполнения матрицы.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int N = 100;

void print_array(int arr[N][N])
{
    //OUTPUT ARRAY
    for( size_t j = 0; j < N ; ++j ) {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            cout << arr[j][i] << "";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int arr[N][N];
    int temp = 0;
    //FILL ARRAY
    for( size_t j = 0; j < N ; ++j ) {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            arr[j][i] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }
    for(size_t j = N - 1, i = 0; j >= 0 && i < N; --j, ++i) temp += arr[i][j];
    for(size_t i = N - 1, j = 1; j < N-1; ++j) temp += arr[i][j];
    for(size_t j = N - 1, i = 1; i < N; ++i) temp += arr[i][j];

    //print_array(arr);
    cout << "Summ is: " << temp << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну и в чем проблема?

Comment: @Alex, увеличь размер стека, либо используй динамические массивы (`int **array = ...` или вообще `vector<vector<int>> arr`) вместо VLA массивов (`int arr[N][N]`)

Comment: @diraria , вектор спас. Есть предложения по улучшению алгоритма сложения?

Comment: Улучшению в плане читаемости или производительности? Куда тут ускорять-то, итак всего три цикла?